# python - Change python to /usr/local/bin/python?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv

I'm trying to install `opencv` using `python2.7`.

When I use `brew install python`. I got

> Warning: python-2.7.11 already installed, it's just not linked

And then I run `brew link python` and `brew install python` again got

> 1 export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
>
> Warning: python-2.7.11 already installed

But `which python` still told me I'm using `/usr/bin/python`.

I changed my `~/.bash_profile` to

```
  1 export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
  2  #Setting PATH for Python 3.5
  3 # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
  4 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
  5 export PATH
  6 # Homebrew
  7 export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

No thing happens. It seems that I should be using `/usr/local/bin/python` because `opencv` is installed by `homebrew`.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try closing your terminal session and then open a new one? `~/.bash_profile` is only picked up when bash is executed as a login shell, which is the default for Terminal.app when you open a new terminal window. Or you can do `source ~/.bash_profile` if you do not want to close the terminal session for some reason.

**Side note:** You might want to add the following at the top of your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

So that your `~/.bashrc` is also executed. Optionally you can also add:

```
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    source `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

To enable bash completion for brew commands.

Comment: Yes I've executed `source ~/.bash_profile` after I edited it but I still got the same result. Also, the two solutions given seems not working for me. Actually I don't know what does `brew link python` do and I thought it would symlink my system python (aka `/usr/bin/python`) with `/usr/local/bin/python`. Is that right? So why aren't they the same?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` tell you? `/usr/local/bin` should come before `/usr/bin/`. `brew link python` will not symlink the homebrew version with the system python, doing so might break system scripts that depend on system python to be at the current version that comes with the OS. It just symlinks whatever latest python version you have in `/usr/local/Cellar/` into `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Homebrew and OSX have switched from putting python in `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin`

You want to do something like:

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

To get the homebrew python.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to `/usr/local/bin` like following:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Works perfectly for me. That's what I want to use.